# Want to download a Git repository, what do I need (windows machine)?

Tags: windows, git

I want to download this open source application, and they are using Git.  What do I need to download the code base?

**Update**
How do I change the working directory when I am using Git Bash?  (I want to download the repo at a certain directory, using pwd tells me I will be downloading the repo where I don't want it.

Comment: Please do not update your question to include a second question. If you have a new question, post a new question. That’s how Stack Overflow is meant to work.

Comment: "I want to download this open source application, and they are using Git. What do I need to download the code base?" -- half a night spare time. Damn :(

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Download [Git on Msys](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/). Then:

```
git clone git://project.url.here
```

Comment: ok that is what I was thinking, just wanted some confirmation thanks.

Comment: sorry for the question: but where do i write `git clone git://project.url.here` after installing msysgit?

Comment: @Foysal: Open the "Git bash" icon, which is a Unix-style command prompt on Windows. Then `cd` into your desired directory and run the above command.

Comment: This is an old question, but as I also found it ...: One thing to note is that `git clone` will download the repository in a *subdirectory* of your current working directory. So you don't create the actual directory yourself but use a parent directory for a number of Git repository. With `git clone git://project.url.here custom-name` you can create a directory with a different name than the original repository name (which is usually not recommendable).

Answer (score 10):

Install [mysysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/).  (Same as Greg Hewgill's answer.)

Install [Tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/).  (Tortoisegit requires mysysgit or something similiar like Cygwin.)

After TortoiseGit is installed, right-click on a folder, select Git Clone..., then enter the Url of the repository, then click Ok.

*This answer is not any better than just installing mysysgit, but you can avoid the dreaded command line.  :)*

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to start a "What's the best unix command line under Windows" war, but have you thought of [*Cygwin*](http://www.cygwin.com)? Git is in the Cygwin package repository.

And you get a lot of beneficial side-effects! (:-)

Comment: Including the dubious side-effect of having a different line-ending convention on windows by default to the rest of your team.

Comment: @Arafangion Cygwin allows you to work with Unix line endings (a setup option, I think).

Comment: Exactly.  The non-cygwin version of git, by default, will use DOS line endings.

Answer (score 1):

To change working directory in GitMSYS's Git Bash you can just use `cd`

cd /path/do/directory

Note that:

- Directory separators use the forward-slash (`/`) instead of backslash.
- Drives are specified with a lower case letter and no colon, e.g. "`C:\stuff`" should be represented with "`/c/stuff`".
- Spaces can be escaped with a backslash (`\`)
- Command line completion is your friend. Press TAB at anytime to expand stuff, including Git options, branches, tags, and directories.

Also, you can right click in Windows Explorer on a directory and "Git Bash here".