# How to use Google's repo tool on MS Windows OS?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, git, python-2.7, repository

I installed git for windows and it works fine(e.g. use one of the following solutions [Want to download a Git repository, what do I need (windows machine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110205/want-to-download-a-git-repository-what-do-i-need-windows-machine)).

[I tried to use `repo` of google](http://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) but it needs [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/) and python 2.7. I installed both and it works fine the only problem is that `repo` script use some unix oriented features such as symbolic links and [fcntl](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html). Is there any alternative code of `repo` for windows?

I couldn't found some native solution by google. if there is one I'll try to push it into google repo git repository or try to use it as is.

Comment: FYI, if you're trying to build Android in Windows, [it's not supported](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).

Comment: Why this question is regarded off-topic ? This growing complexity of regulations really defeat the purpose of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes, Google `repo` script can be compliant with Windows. Follow the steps below.**

But before, as [Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14224458/938111) said `repo` as not been ported on Windows. `repo` (`forall.py`) uses [`fcntl` that is not available on Windows (Unix only)](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fcntl.html?highlight=fcntl#fcntl).

However there is [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) and its own `python` and `git` tools.

If `git` version from MSysGit project for you or if you love your `git` GUI that is based on MSysGit only, then follow the following steps. These steps ensure that [Cygwin can create native NTFS symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659632/938111). Else if the `git` from Cygwin is sufficient, you do not have to do it. But it is better as setting `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native` tells Cygwin to use native NTFS symlinks instead of old Cygwin workaround.

1. Use Windows Vista or later (or switch to Linux)
2. Have Admin privileges
3. Dowload and install Cygwin (32 or 64 bits)
4. Select and install `python` and `git` (and `gpg` if you want) from Cygwin installer
5. Set `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native` in your Cygwin shell:

   ```
   export CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native
   mkdir NEW_DIR
   cd    NEW_DIR
   repo init -u YOUR_URL
   repo sync -j 7
   ```

(see also [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18639953/938111))

Comment: I've had partial success using this approach, however I am still getting seemingly random `0 [main] git-remote-https 69956 child_info_fork::abort: C:\cygwin\bin\cygldap-2-4-2.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x3A0000) != child(0x370000)
error: cannot fork() for fetch-pack: Resource temporarily unavailable` errors.

Comment: Hi @friederbluemle. I do not understand when your error occurs. Please post a new question where you can give more details. I will be pleased to help you. After posting your question, just add a new comment here. Then I will take time to reproduce your case. And maybe someone else will find the trick... Cheers ;)

Comment: @olibre you are my hiro :D - fast way to use repo on windows :)

Answer (score 10):

A working repo tool for windows is available here: https://github.com/esrlabs/git-repo

It requires Python 3+ and git 1.7.2+

Btw, the original forked repo version seems pretty old, so it might not contain all current functionalities.

Comment: The readme for the project states that Python 3+ is experimental only: `Note: Python 3.x is supported on an experimental bases by git-repo
`

Answer (score 8):

There is an alternative for whoever has a choice to work with an alternative to repo, it's called [gclient](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/depottools/gclient).

See [Google's depot tools](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/depottools):

> gclient: Meta-checkout tool managing both subversion and git
>   checkouts. It is similar to repo tool except that it works on Linux,
>   OS X, and Windows and supports both svn and git. On the other hand,
>   gclient doesn't integrate any code review functionality.

Comment: @Mogsdad I think this answer is super relevant. In addition I believe the question is still ultra actual.

Comment: Just today I had the same question and the answer is super-relevant.

Comment: Thanks @0x90 for this answer, I had no idea gclient existed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no native `repo` for Windows currently.

You may use a Linux virtual machine or dual-boot, or work around the (relatively minor) issues caused by symlinks not functioning on your filesystem.

Another option would be to just use `git` directly instead of using the `repo` as a convenience wrapper - `repo` is a support tool, and doesn't add any substantial power.

Answer (score 0):

[git-repo](https://git-repo.info/en/) created by Alibaba works on Linux, Mac and Windows. You may try it.