# Installing Repo

Tags: android, git

I am trying to install the ADK: http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html#audio-dock. 
There I have to install repo: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#installing-repo 
I do not understand the first step. Where do I have to enter this Code?
Do I have to create a Folder called bin?
Where can I download the repo tool?

Please help me
Fabian

Comment: You need to run those commands on your terminal. Which OS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

As [Jonathan.Brink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2295034/jonathan-brink) has pointed, it depends on the OS you are using. 
But frankly independent from the OS it consist of the following 4 parts.

1. Yes, you have to first create a *bin* folder in your home directory. You could use either a File Manager or terminal. Google prefer terminal.

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin
   ```
2. Secondly you should put the *bin* directory in your PATH.

   ```
   PATH=~/bin:$PATH
   ```

This is like saying *"In this directory I have put some special code. Treat it as an application"*

3. Then you have to download the actual *repo* application. You could either use *curl* command as google suggest

   ```
   curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
   ```

or [this url](https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo). If you download the file on your own, you should put it in the *bin* directory you have created.

4. The file is a python script. So you have to give it permission to execute. To do so you have to use the terminal again:

   ```
   chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
   ```

If you have any questions, I'll be happy to answer them :)

P.S.: If you are using Windows, you could use [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223302/is-there-a-version-of-googles-repo-tool-for-windows) discussed a post already

Comment: You could use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18652851/2935386) as a guide to installing repo on Windows