# How to make use of Windows Git for Google repo tool in cygwin (over Windows)?

Tags: git, cygwin, repo

I have installed git (the MinGW one) and cygwin on Windows 10. For Cygwin I have installed curl, gpg and python packages. No installation of Git on Cygwin, so Git for windows is the one which is used as Git in Cygwin.

I am following installation steps for repo tool from
https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#installing-repo

But repo init command does not work.  It shows the output as below:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
$
```

When I install git in cygwin then the same steps works fine. 
Any idea how to use Git for Windows with repo (I do not want to use git from cygwin). I have used the steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18652851/1624792 to make use of Git installed on Windows, but that does not work.